# Is it possible to start or stop pods based on some events?

Tags: kubernetes, microservices

Is it possible to start or stop Kubernets PODS based on some events like a Kafka event?

For e.g., if there is an event that some work is complete and based on that I want to bring down a POD or bring a POD up. In my case, minimum replicas of the PODs keep running even though they are not required to be running for the most part of the day.

Comment: You can use the kubernetes API , import it in python , do the decesion logic and stop the pods using API

Answer (score 1):

Pods with [Horizontal Pod Autoscaling](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) based on [custom metrics](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#support-for-custom-metrics) is the option you are looking for.

Probably you instrument your code with custom Prometheus metrics. In your case it is publishing a metric in Prometheus that says the number of messages available for processing at a point in time. Then use that custom Prometheus metric to scale pods on that basis.